# Google Endpoints, the API explorer works locally but does not work after deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

worked perfectly locally but the explorer is stuck in "Loading.." when deployed. Steps I took so far:

- cleared browser cache
- checked the logs, I have no errors and i DONT    see a
  "/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 200 " request, so thats    a
  issue and I dont know how to fix.
- The link:
  https://.appspot.com/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
  results in: {"state": "APPLICATION_ERROR", "error_message": "Not
  Found"}

Please point me in the right direction to debug this. thanks in advance

my app.yaml file

```
application: appID
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi.*
  script: the_api.APPLICATION

- url: /favicon\.ico
static_files: favicon.ico
upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /js
static_dir: static/js


- url: /.*
script: the_web_page.app
secure: always


libraries:


- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0

- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a simple error. To fix I changed the line

```
- url: /_ah/spi.*
```

in the app.yaml file to

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
```

what I find hard to explain is why the first worked in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the yellow "Loading" status in my API Explorer on deployment and I was struggling to understand why - I had not changed any of my code but suddenly the API explorer stopped working. 
All I did was to clear out my internet explorer temporary files, cookies and website data and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me whenever I use Opera.i don't know if this is what you are using but try another browser.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you placing your app name before `.appspot.com...`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using HTTPS. Endpoints in production only work using a secure connection.

Comment: even this is not working, I edited my answer with the app.yaml file I'm using. please let me know what you think. Thank you

Comment: app.yaml looks good to me. If you use the Chrome tools inspector what do you see in the network section? I don't see any link with https://.appspot.com/_ah/spi/* I only see https://.appspot.com/_ah/api/* calls. Do you see any error or status different than 200?

Comment: I missed that one slash, that had to be hard to debug. Thanks to you, now I'll be extra careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly stopped working.
When I click on the Endpoint, it just change the url in the address bar of the browser but doesn't load it.
So I copied the url from the address bar and loaded the url directly and it worked.